# android can intent executes another apps code

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm in the middle of an app where a function is implemented in its code. I have an intent too. Can this function be executed by this intent on its space. I mean like it iss intents code.

Comment: can you provide a sample? I don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Think it like My app have a function fn() which actually don't have the permission to do a task. But my intent got the permission to do the task. Can my intent execute this fn() with his permission.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am not certain but think this is not possible. It would go against all security policies android cares about.